# Ez_Setup error 'AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping''

Tags: python, android, module, attributeerror, androidviewclient

I downloaded the script ez-setup (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py). But whenever I try to run it I get the error "AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'" how can I fix it?

I already tried to reinstall python etc. but nothing of this works.

Comment: I Need this for installing "https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient".

Answer (score 0):

To install [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki) you just need to run

```
pip install androidviewclient
```

as described [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#using-a-virtual-environment).

If this is not your problem please provide more details about your environment, OS, etc.